# Are "Dequeue" and "acknowledge" equivalent concept in activemq?

Tags: activemq-classic

I mean dequeue count in the web console, and acknowledge() method in activemq broker's code.

When one message run acknowledge(), the dequeue count will always add 1 ,is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you acknowledge a message that has been queued then it is dequeued and so the dequeued count for the destination increases by one yes.